# Como Recuperar valor de variável em uma janela modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, modal

Meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho esse código que exibe vários carros em uma tabela:

```
<?php
$veiculos = "SELECT * from veiculo ";
$veiculos .= "WHERE id_secretaria = '1' ORDER BY placa DESC LIMIT 2"; //mudar conforme o id da secretaria
$query_veiculos = mysqli_query($conexao,$veiculos);
if(!$query_veiculos) {
die("Falha na consulta ao banco");
}
while ( $exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($query_veiculos)) {
$placa = $exibir["placa"];
?>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mostrar-veiculo" data-id='$placa' id="btnEditar"><?php  echo "Modelo: ".$exibir["modelo"]." | Placa: ".$placa." ";?><i class="ti-car pull-right"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Ao clicar no link abre um modal com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
include('../conecta-db.php');

$placa = $_POST["placa"];

$veiculos = "SELECT * from veiculo ";
$veiculos .= "WHERE placa = '{$placa}'";
$query_veiculos = mysqli_query($conexao,$veiculos);
if(!$query_veiculos) {
die("Falha na consulta ao banco");
}

?>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="mostrar-veiculo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Veiculo selecionado</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     <!--Lista com os cadastros-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="container">


  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead class="bg-primary">
      <tr style="color: #fff;">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Placa</th>
        <th scope="col">Modelo</th>
        <th scope="col">Ano</th>
        <th scope="col">Km Rodados</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php $i = 1;?>

      <?php 
        while ( $exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($query_veiculos)) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $exibir["placa"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $exibir["modelo"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $exibir["ano"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $exibir["km_rodados"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php $i++;} ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="botao-fechar" style="width: 90%;
display: table;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: static;">Fechar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quero saber como posso recuperar o valor da variável placa no modal para chamar apenas a linha que tem a mesma placa no banco de dados.
seguem imagens do sistema:

Aqui os links dos carros:
[image: links]

Aqui o modal onde deve exibir todas as informações do carro:
[image: modal]

Comment: É um ajax?.....

Comment: E essa tabela `Carros desta secretária (ou seria secretaria?)` qual é a dela? Surgiu sem mais nem menos no meio da pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pode fazer como eu, é meio que uma gambiarra, mas me serviu. É só tu colocar esse código dentro de uma função e chama-la por um onClick().

```
$('#idDaModal').modal();
$("#idDoInput").val(variavalAqui);
```

Aí tu só cria uma input com type = hidden que irá receber esse valor. Não sei se entendi direito, mas espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou =(

Comment: Marlon, dê uma olhada nesse código aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/o5fa6k7L/ ele faz o que eu te disse lá em cima, caso atenda à suas necessidades implemente-o ao seu código

Comment: Poxa ajudou muito, obrigado!

Comment: De nada, Marlon